# Keeping association and saving multiple child records with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class SequenceResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sequence_result
  belongs_to :rating_prototype
end

class RatingPrototype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Every sequence result can have multiple ratings. A rating's structure is defined by the rating prototype, e.g. the prototype gives a certain question "What is your rating?" and the answer itself is stored in the `Rating` class.

So when I build a form, I already fill the `ratings` with their prototype:

```
def new_ratings
  @sequence_result = SequenceResult.find(params[:sequence_result_id])

  # create empty ratings
  RatingPrototype.all.each do |rating_prototype|
    @sequence_result.ratings.new(rating_prototype: rating_prototype)
  end
end
```

Then I create my form:

```
<%= form_for @sequence_result do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :ratings do |rating_form| %>
    <%= rating_form.text_area :answer %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now, when I submit this, my params look as follows:

```
"sequence_result" => {
  "ratings_attributes" => { 
    "0" => { "answer" => "test" },
    "1" => { "answer" => "2" }
  }
},
"sequence_result_id" => "1"
```

As you can see, I don't know anymore to which `RatingPrototype` every `Rating` belonged. This means that in my controller, when saving from those parameters, I manually have to assign the `RatingPrototype` to those new models again.

Is there any easier way to keep the association when saving, so that all I need to do is:

```
params[:sequence_result][:ratings_attributes].each_value do |rating_attr|
  @sequence_result.ratings.new(rating_attr)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather simple, but I'm still surprised there's no easier way to pass this along.

In the form, I had to include a `rating_prototype_id` field that is later passed to the parameters for saving.

```
<%= rating_form.hidden_field :rating_prototype_id, value: rating_form.object.rating_prototype.id %>
```